# Something like PPerl for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, daemon

I've used [PPerl](http://search.cpan.org/~MSERGEANT/PPerl-0.25/PPerl.pm) for deamon like processes.

> This program turns ordinary perl
>   scripts into long running daemons,
>   making subsequent executions extremely
>   fast. It forks several processes for
>   each script, allowing many proceses to
>   call the script at once.

Does anyone know of something like this for ruby? Right now I am planing on using a wrapper around curl to call a REST WebService written in Sinatra running on JRuby. I'm hoping there is a simpler option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at using [nailgun](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/JRubyWithNailgun)? It sets up a background JVM process that your scripts execute in. That way you can use jruby w/o incurring the JVM startup time you would normally get with each script run.

Answer (score -1):

You mean like [daemons](http://daemons.rubyforge.org/)?

Simple example of in-process daemonization

```
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'daemons'

  Daemons.daemonize


  loop do
    `touch /tmp/me`
    sleep 1
  end
```

Also, instead of using curl, have you looked at [rest-client](http://github.com/archiloque/rest-client#readme)?

Comment: It's not a library you load into your script (the equivalent of that in Perl would be something like Proc::Daemon). It's outside of the script and doesn't require any modification.

Comment: (Foolishly reads pperl docs which he should have to begin with) So you want to cache your script in memory to minimize start-up times? Are you using MRI or jruby?

Comment: The script I am using has a startup time of 2.1 seconds. I'd like it to be under 0.1 if possible. I can use MRI or JRuby.

Comment: Have you looked at using nailgun? http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/JRubyWithNailgun

Comment: @BaroqueBobcat nailgun seems to solve the problem. not perfect and I needed to tweak the WS calls a bit but this seems to solve the startup lag time problem.

Comment: @BaroqueBobcat, you should add that as a second answer